# why am I not able to filter events by month in django?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models

I have below django views to filter events based on month

```
class FilterByMonthView(ListView):
    model = Event
    template_name = 'your_template.html'
    context_object_name = 'filtered_data'

    def get_queryset(self):
        month = self.kwargs.get('month')
        month = str(month).zfill(2)

        # Construct a date range for the specified month
        start_date = datetime.strptime(f'2023-{month}-01 00:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        end_date = datetime.strptime(f'2023-{month}-01 23:59:59', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        # Assuming end of the month

        # Filter the data based on the date range
        queryset = Event.objects.filter(
            event_date__range=(start_date, end_date)
        )
        return queryset
```

Below is my models.py

```
class Event(models.Model):
    emp_id = models.IntegerField(max_length=50)
    event_type = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    event_date = models.DateTimeField()
    email = models.EmailField()

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.event_type} {self.event_date} {self.email}"
```

In the django admin page when I am creating an event, I see below output

```
ID  Emp id  Event type  Event date           Email 
6   67565   Birthday    Nov. 15,2010,6 a.m. jhad@jhsd.com
```

Below is the urls.py for project level and app level respectively

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('emp/', include('EVENTS.urls')),

]


from django.urls import path
from .views import FilterByMonthView

urlpatterns = [
    path('filter/<int:month>/', FilterByMonthView.as_view(), name='filter-by-month'),
]
```

HTML looks as below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Filtered Events</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Events for the Selected Month</h1>
    <ul>
        {% for event in filtered_data %}
            <li>{{ event.event_date }} - {{ event.event_name }}</li>
            <!-- Display other event attributes as needed -->
        {% empty %}
            <li>No events found for this month.</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

I am seeing "`No events found for this month.`" in my browser.

below is the sample url that I am using

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/emp/filter/11/
```

I suspect the issue seems to be with the date format. But not sure. Please suggest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The year in your table is, 2010, hence that is outside the range.

But if you only want to match the month, not the year, you are overcomplicating things a lot. You can just work with:

```
class FilterByMonthView(ListView):
    model = Event
    template_name = 'your_template.html'
    context_object_name = 'filtered_data'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return (
            super().get_queryset().filter(event_date__month=self.kwargs['month'])
        )
```